# PHP - How to get hold of selected choice and pass to db

Tags: php

I have to implement a dropdown list to select a customer from db, and then get that customer's orders from db.

My codes below is able to show the list of customers in the drop down box.

```
$query_customer = "SELECT customer FROM Customer;";
$result_customer = mysqli_query($connect, $query_customer);

<select>
<option value="" disabled selected>--- Select Customer ---</option>
<?php while($row_customer = mysqli_fetch_array($result_customer)) { ?>
<option> <?php echo $row_customer["customer"]; ?> </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

I intend to get that customer's orders from db with codes below.

```
$customer = $_GET['customer'];
$query_order = "SELECT order FROM Customer where customer = '$customer';";
$result_order = mysqli_query($connect, $query_order);
```

My problem is: how can I get hold of the customer selected, and pass to this code $_GET['customer']?

I've spent an hour on this problem. Please could someone help. Thank you.

==========================================================

Based on the comments I revised codes below.

```
$query_customer = "SELECT customer FROM Customer;";
$result_customer = mysqli_query($connect, $query_customer);

<select name="customer">
<option value="" disabled selected>--- Select Customer ---</option>
<?php while($row_customer = mysqli_fetch_array($result_customer)) { ?>
<option> <?php echo $row_customer["customer"]; ?> </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>


$customer = $_GET['customer']; //Warning: Undefined array key "customer"
$query_order = "SELECT order FROM Customer where customer = '$customer';";
$result_order = mysqli_query($connect, $query_order);

<p><?php echo $result_order['order']; ?></p> //Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array
```

fyi the Customer table has 10 customers and each customer has exactly one order. The result should be a single value of an order of the selected customer.

I got a warning and an error as stated above. Please advise a proper way to implement the codes.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You need `name="customer"` in the `<select>`

Comment: your code has SQL Injection Possibility, Try to use `mysqli_prepare` when u want to use variable/ user input for the query.

Answer (score 1):

In your `<select>` opening tag you need `name="customer"`

Like this: `<select name="customer">`

[Look through the documentation for html forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve as below

```
$query_customer = "SELECT customer FROM Customer;";
    $result_customer = mysqli_query($connect, $query_customer);
    
    <select name="customer">
    <option value="" disabled selected>--- Select Customer ---</option>
    <?php while($row_customer = mysqli_fetch_array($result_customer)) { ?>
    <option> <?php echo $row_customer["customer"]; ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```